# Odd session / url error

Tags: php, session

I have a really weird error with a page on my site, and in particular at only one url.

I have a PHP include on the very first line of the page. The very first line of the included file is `session_start();`

I get this error when the page loads:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by... //etc

This is odd enough as the session start is the very first thing on the page and there are no other attempts to start a session. However there's something even weirder going on...

I have many other pages that use basically identical code with different content and they work fine with no errors. I replaced the entire code in the problem page with the code from another page, basically creating a clone. ***When loading the page the error still happens!*** WTH?

Any ideas?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: do you post back the page?, do you include nesting php file?

Comment: @urfusion I'm pretty sure the code is only going to obvuscate the question. I'll gladly post if someone can hint at what the issue might be but I don't want this post to get bogged down with pointless code, you know what happens then.

Comment: @C.Fasolin - There is a form on the page which uses post and there are no nested includes.

Comment: normally `headers already sent by` error show when you are using header but there is something printing before that.

Comment: @urfusion Thanks, as mentioned it's the very first line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have problem with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), some editors don't display this mark, so you can't see it, but it's send to browser before session starts.

**How to remove BOM on Windows Notepad++**

[Remove a BOM character in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986445/remove-a-bom-character-in-a-file)

**Linux using awk**

[Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

Comment: Er...OK. What's the solution? Also, as mentioned I copied the entire code from a working page and got the same error.

Comment: You'r using Linux or Windows or Mac? You need some editor that will show you this mark so you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Windows, I think the host is using Linux. I'm using Notepad++ (see comment in other answer)

Answer (score 2):

It may be problem with BOM, use `Notepad++` to solve this

- Download Notepad++ and open the file there, delete all fancy characters before the
- Make sure there is no whitespace character like " " or tab or linebreak before the
- In Notepad++ click Encoding and then UTF-8 without BOM to convert the file to UTF-8 without BOM, then save it.
- Also add ob_start(); before session_start(); to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using Notepad++ but I followed your other instructions and get the same error.