# Copy from file ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "ï»¿1"

Tags: r, postgresql, psql, rpostgresql

I'm using PostgresSQL 10 and RPostgreSQL package in R.

I create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    birthdate date,
    deathdate date
);
```

Then attempt to copy the file :

```
COPY people (id, name, birthdate, deathdate) 
  FROM '\people.sql'
  ENCODING 'UTF-8';
```

Then get the following error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input syntax
for integer: "ï»¿1" CONTEXT:  COPY people, line 1, column id: "ï»¿1"
```

I did wonder if this was an encoding error, so ran and got:

```
readr::guess_encoding("\people.sql")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      encoding confidence
         <chr>      <dbl>
1        UTF-8       1.00
2 windows-1252       0.37
3 windows-1254       0.37
4 windows-1250       0.28
```

I've tried the other, less probable windows encodings, but this do not work either and throws similar issues with line 1, for instance windows-1252 shows ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Ã¯Â»Â¿1"

The first few lines of the file are:

```
1   50 Cent 1975-07-06  \N
2   A. Michael Baldwin  1963-04-04  \N
```

and the last two lines :

```
8396    Zubaida Sahar   \N  \N
8397    Zuhair Haddad   \N  \N 
\.
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe there is a BOM (Byte Order Mark) in the file? You can check this by hexdumping the file and looking at the first three characters.

Comment: Thanks - I've used Notepad++ to Convert to UTF-8, to remove any BOM. 
 This now reads the file, however it throws an error of

"RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  end-of-copy marker corrupt
CONTEXT:  COPY people, line 8398".

Line 8398 is the end of file which is \.

Comment: A new error or that same one?

Comment: "RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR: end-of-copy marker corrupt CONTEXT: COPY people, line 8398". Line 8398 is the end of file which is \.

Comment: Maybe remove the `\.` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wildplasser in the comments for this one:

1 - Remove the Byte Order Mark - I used Notepad++ and convert to UTF-8 [(see this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986445/remove-a-bom-character-in-a-file)

2 - Completely removed the erroneous end of file marker which was

```
\.
```