# Doctype not appearing /ufeff before it

Tags: wordpress, encoding, utf-8, doctype

I'm using wordpress for months and everything worked until today.

In my header.php I have my !DOCTYPE html, however it doesn't appear in my page.

I'm using chrome devtools to debug my code and when I look the source file I see a red dot before the doctype then when I mouse over it I see /ufeff.

Furthermore, in my code I have &#65279 right after /head tag that's make a kind of blank space between my header and my body.

I tried to change the encoding to utf-8 with notepad++ without success.

I tried all day to fix this issue and now I looking for some help.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in a code snippet so we can take a closer look at it.

Comment: Basically, I can't post the whole page and I can't post the doctype with the red dot from chrome dev tools. Do you need something specific ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

There are lots of answers which might help you, such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986445/remove-a-bom-character-in-a-file).

Comment: I read about it.

That's why I said I tried to change the encoding without success.
I mean, the encoding seems to be utf-8 without bom, but I still have the issue.

Comment: Can you post the file somewhere? If you still see /ufeff somewhere, that BOM is still there.

Comment: Likely there are BOMs in other files too. Wordpress is including a ton of PHP files into each other. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543595/496046

Comment: You are right, it's probably still there, but there's nothing before the doctype in my header.php. 

Right, however, I tried to change the encoding to all php files.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to search your other files. Another answer in the link I just gave gives a grep command which can help find them.

Comment: Alright, I tried the grep command on my theme directory and still nothing.

Comment: Then I can't help further without looking at your code.

Comment: Even on the wordpress dashboard I have the same bom without the doctype. Proabably not the theme.