# compilation error in angular project: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec.js 1:2
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Once I start a new angular project, it compiles the first time, but while connected to the internet, it brings this error and doesn't compile again.

Comment: Can you please share with us the regex or your `regexp.exec` file please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1:1 error Parsing error: Unexpected character '�'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349355/11-error-parsing-error-unexpected-character)