# Google Cloud 'Import failed: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff Import error: exit status 3'

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, ascii, google-cloud-sql, pg-dump

I'm trying to upload a pg_dump file from a postgres 9.6 database that I just built locally on my Windows machine up into Google Cloud SQL.  I have followed the directions on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting) as best I can on my Windows machine (I mannually commented out the "EXTENSION" statements in the dump file).  I then uploaded the pg_dump file to a Google Cloud Bucket, and finally tried to import the pg_dump'ed file into Google Cloud SQL.  I keep getting the following error:

```
Import failed: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff Import error: exit status 3
```

I've looked around and on Stack Overflow and some similar posts suggested putting in a additional arguments to specify the encoding.  I've tried the following 3 pg_dump commands and none of them seem to be compatible with Google Cloud's import process.  Any ideas?

```
pg_dump -U [USER_NAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DB_NAME] > dbexport.sql

pg_dump --encoding=ISO88591 -U [USER_NAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DB_NAME] > dbexport.sql

pg_dump --encoding=UTF8 -U [USER_NAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DB_NAME] > dbexport.sql
```

I also did a search in the .sql file using Notepad++ for "\x{0xff}" per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/985570/how-do-i-find-this-characterby-unicode-search-in-notepad-%EF%BB%81-ufec1-and-only/986109) and several upper/lower case variants and couldn't find that character in the file anywhere.

Comment: BOM issue? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: supposedly 0xFF is equal to "ÿ", but I doubt that character is in my database.

Comment: If it was a BOM issue, what should I try differently than I am currently doing?

Comment: check the first to byte, to  be sure it is caused by BOM, this could happen when you open exported sql edit & save notepad automatically add BOM, if thats the case remove the first two byte and then upload to cloud. [Bom & Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986445/remove-a-bom-character-in-a-file)

Comment: Awesome!  That did it!  I just had to encode the file as UTF-8 in Notepad++ and then save it.  That version loaded into Google Cloud SQL with no issues.  @cske, write that up as an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when dump file was modified, your editor added [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the file.
Remove the first two bytes of file (eg. [Bom & Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986445/remove-a-bom-character-in-a-file)) to be able to import it.