# Spring MessageSource properties file first line not detected

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring 4 and use MessageSource for localization.

My xml file has:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/myfile"/> 
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

One of the localization files, myfile_nl.properties has:

```
prop1=abc
other1=o1
other2=o2
other3=o3
```

The Java code to get the localized string is:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

String localizedMsg = messageSource.getMessage("prop1", null, locale);
```

Now, I get exception that prop1 is not found.
So, I edited the properties file to copy the prop1 later in the file.

```
other1=o1
other2=o2
prop1=abc
other3=o3
```

And now prop1 was detected.

Why is prop1 not getting detected when it was on first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your properties file, in UTF-8, probably starts with a BOM ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

Since Java doesn't do BOMs, the [3-byte BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) is treated as the non-displayable BOM character, and becomes part of the name of the property listed in the first line, which of course will make it not match.

Edit the file in a text editor that can save the file without a BOM.

Notepad++ is an example of such a text editor. See: [Remove a BOM character in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32986445/5221149).